# Javascript event conflict, but not sure how to identify the first event assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-events

I have an element `<div class='graph'>` and I try to associate an `onClick` event with it. There are some dynamic loading process on top of this element, but I am not sure what the event handler does the process load exactly.

For example, after open the web page, I use highchart to plot a chart on `<div class='graph'>` and then I tried to add an event handler `$('.graph').on('click',function(){//to show some text when click the <div>}`, but unfortunately, this does not work (the function never execute when I click over the element). The only think I could image is that the highchart added some 'click' event over `'.graph'`. So when I add another 'click' event, it will not work as expected.

My question is:

1. how could I know what's the first 'click' event (by `console.log($('.graph').click())` seems not giving me any useful info)?
2. how should I make my second click successful?

Comment: `.on()` adds an event listener. An element can have multiple event listeners, and all will be fired. However, maybe the click is disabled with [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), or another event listener stops the propagation of the event before it reaches your element.

Comment: It would be nice to see some source code

Comment: maybe try to take all event listeners off first with .off() and then put your event listener .on().

Comment: @Oriol Thanks for your answer. Maybe it is another event listener stops the propagation. But how could I analysis this? How could I find which event stop the propagation?

Comment: @L4zl0w Thanks for your answer. I did try to use .off() on '.graph' and then use .on('click',function(){console.log('clicked')}). However, the click event is still not triggered for some reason.....

Comment: Look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code you can find [line #9946](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/785ec52bb91457087b211cf839c3a87b6e416b17/js/highcharts.src.js#L9946) (for 4.1.7) - which prevents default method, however, there you won't find `stopPropagation()` call.

I suggest to use [`chart.events.click`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click) instead.